# I can't play Paladins with Wine

Tags: wine, games, steam, playonlinux

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and I would like to play the free game *Paladins: Champions of the Realm* using Wine and PlayonLinux. According to [this](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=34269), Wine should run it well in the said version, but it is not working for me.

I've successfully configured Wine and installed the game. After the installation the launcher started the game automatically. But after I closed it for the first time, there is no way I can run it again.

Wine created two launcher shortcuts in the desktop, plus the Hi-Rez (the game's company) launcher. The automatically created launchers are unfunctional, and the one Wine asked to be created manually displays the error message "Failed to initialize assembly file" (I googled it, but I found no solution). Trying to launch these files in their directories doesn't make any difference.

After watching some tutorials I was able to at least launch the game for the first time as I said, but this error makes the game unplayable. Do any of you are aware of a possible solution? Thanks.

Remark: *Paladins* is not a listed software, so I'm not using the Steam version.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to run the game by asking PlayonLinux to create shortcuts of all *Paladins*-related launchers after the installation, including those of Hi-Rez. Then, I start one of launchers from PlayonLinux menu (this one in the image) and I'm able to launch the game from it. However, it cannot keep you logged, so you need to type your full login and password every time you launch it. Sometimes it takes a lot to load, and the game may crash if you try to minimize its window, but it works anyway.

[image]

[image]